# Convert Type parameter to T

Tags: c#, generics, xmlserializer, xelement

I'm a little stumped on how to pass in a type argument to a Method, from a parameter.

```
public class MyNamespaceXmlFormatter : XmlMediaTypeFormatter
{
    public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, 
                                            Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, 
                                            TransportContext transportContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        XElement xmloutput = XElementSerialiser.ToXElement<type>(value);

        ...........
```

I've tried the following, but these fail as well;

```
XElement xmloutput = XElementSerialiser.ToXElement<(T)type>(value);

XElement xmloutput = XElementSerialiser.ToXElement<typeof(type)>(value);
```

Obviously this compiles, but makes little sense;

```
XElement xmloutput = XElementSerialiser.ToXElement<Type>(value);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generic instantiation (i.e. adding `<T>` to signature) is a compile-time construct, while `Type` object exists at runtime.

It would be preferable, as D Stanley suggested, to make the whole method generic and not pass a `Type` object at all.
However, if you're unable to do that, you can make yourself a generic factory with non-generic interface, and create instances of it dynamically. Like so:

```
interface IFactory {
    XElement ToXElement( object value );
}

class Factory<T> : IFactory {
    public XElement ToXElement( object value ) { 
        return XElementSerialiser.ToXElement<T>( value ); 
    }
}

public override Task WriteToStreamAsync( Type type, object value, 
                                    Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, 
                                    TransportContext transportContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
    var factory = Activator.CreateInstance( typeof( Factory<> ).MakeGenericType( type ) ) as IFactory;
    return factory.ToXElement( value );
}
```

For performance reasons, you might also want to cache the `factory` instance.

**UPDATE:** made a [blog post](http://fsoikin.blogspot.com/2014/05/dynamic-generics-in-net.html) out of it.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a lot of overhead in the simple case that you're trying to call a generic static method from a static method taking a type argument, as in your blog post.

Comment: Too much overhead compared with what?

Comment: A lot of overhead in terms of extra classes that have to be written and instantiated and potentially cached. I'm certainly not saying this is a bad solution, just that it would be nice if doing something simple like calling a non-generic method from a generic one (as compared to the reverse, which is trivial) was... well, simple.

Comment: Calling a non-generic method from a generic one is simple, you can just do it.

Answer (score 4):

You *could* do it using generics, but could you make `WriteToStreamAsync` generic instead?

```
public override Task WriteToStreamAsync<T>(object value, 
                                        Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, 
                                        TransportContext transportContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    XElement xmloutput = XElementSerialiser.ToXElement<T>(value);
```

Comment: I thought that but it looks like its probably overriding something in `System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeFormatter` so may not be an option...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with D Stanley's answer but in case you want to have the compiler infer the type of the object to be serialized for you so you don't have to specify it each time you use the method use this:

```
public override Task WriteToStreamAsync<T>(T value, 
                                        Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, 
                                        TransportContext transportContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    XElement xmloutput = XElementSerialiser.ToXElement<T>(value);
```

Comment: Yes, I could overload the method but I'd still have to cast type to T somehow.

Comment: You don't really need to pass the `Type` anymore. It would be inferred by the compiler for you. You just call `WriteToStreamAsync(serializeThis, stream, ...)`